# randomForest's importance only contains MeanDecreaseGini

Tags: r, data-mining, random-forest

I have two scripts which both generate random forests in **R**, which as far as I can work out have the same inputs, although my problem suggests this isn't the case. One of them returns an importance table containing

`row.names  importance.blue importance.red  importance.MeanDecreaseAccuracy importance.MeanDecreaseGini`

the other importance table just contains

```
row.names   MeanDecreaseGini
```

Whats the difference between these two forests, and more importantly what's causing the difference given what I thought were identical inputs?

(The scripts are too large to paste here, but both are trying to predict a factor on the basis of a bunch of continuous variables)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The help page of randomForest tells us, that importance (when used for classification) is a matrix with nclass + 2 columns. The first nclass columns are the class-specific measures computed as mean descrease in accuracy. The nclass + 1st column is the mean descrease in accuracy over all classes. The last column is the mean decrease in Gini index.
If importance=FALSE, the last measure is still returned as a vector.

So, it seems to me, that you called randomForest once with importance=TRUE and once with importance=FALSE.

Comment: Damn. Your entirely correct answer means that this isn't the source of my bug, and makes it look like I can't read a manual. Cheers for being right though. :-)